# Lost ability to edit code in AWS Lambda console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, console

I have several Lambdas deployed to AWS, all created as single file function in the console.  All was working fine until I flushed my caches and cookies in chrome.  Then the function codes will no longer show up in the browser, any browser, I tried 3.  Also all the Lambda functions think they are all zip file based so I cannot reenter the code from my git repo.  The functions still operate properly, I just cannot edit them.

All new functions I create are also not in console editing mode. Something general / global has changed, not specific to any one function.

What can cause this?  And across all browsers?

Most importantly how can I fix this?

[image: Screen Shot From Console]

Comment: After much googling and just playing with the console I figured this out.  By clearing my cookies in chrome that code tab in Lambda closed - across all browsers and computer.  I just needed to double click on "lambda_function.py" to the left of the code area.  Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can download your code as a zip file if you click right on `Actions > Export Function` and then `Download deployment package`. Maybe re-uploading the packages will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't change anything.  I'm trying to get back to console editing.  This looks to be a global change as any new Lambda I make is in the same mode.